# .net Compact Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Will their be a new release of the compact framework with VS2010 and .net 4.0 and if so what new features will it include? 
WPF? 
linq to SQL?
etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 only supports developing for windows phone 7. This is a silver light based framework, it does not support win forms or native code.

VS2010 can not be used to develop for Windows Mobile 6.5 or lower.

You can however install VS2008 along side VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

From what I heard from guys in redmond, there will be a mobile silverlight platform for both windows mobile and nokia (symbian, I think).
The "silverlight mobile" platform should be built on top of the compact framework, so it will NOT be a port of the desktop version.

There seems to be an information embargo on Windows Mobile right now, but I think things will be much clearer once Windows Mobile 7 is out.

Comment: I have to say that I am a bit frustrated that MS can't seem to support its own mobile OS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about 4.0 for compact devices (although it seems likely),
and I don't know about WPF either, but I can tell you they are going to provide Silverlight for mobile devices giving you access to a subset of WPF.

Haven't found any other references yet...

Comment: Access to a subset of WPF but not from the compact framework. You can't use Silverlight from the compact framework. Sure you can use a web browser control to show a silverlight app. But it cant talk to the compact framework. You might as well display it is a normal browser instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can go [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010?wa=wsignin1.0) and vote to have Microsoft add Compact Framework Support for Visual Studio 2010.

**UPDATE**: MS has more or less abandoned existing feature requests in Connect.  Please go to the new [User Voice site to vote](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2145313-bring-back-support-for-smart-device-extensions) for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There's an unofficial release of CF 3.7 kicking around the intertubes:

http://www.google.com/search?q=compact+framework+3.7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1

It appears that someone ripped it off a ROM image and dropped it in a torrent.