# Updates to .NET Compact Framework in 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile, compact-framework

This question ([.net Compact Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245566/net-compact-framework-4-0)) asked this back before the release of VS 2010.  The answer basically said to wait for the release.

Now that the release is here, does anyone know?  Is there an upgrade/update to the .NETCF?  something past .NETCF 3.5?

**Update: You can go [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010?wa=wsignin1.0) and vote to have Microsoft add this feature.**

**LATER UPDATE:** MS has more or less abandoned existing feature requests in Connect.  Please go to the new [User Voice site to vote](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2145313-bring-back-support-for-smart-device-extensions) for this feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245566/net-compact-framework-4-0

Comment: Since this is a duplicate question, I suggest you ask in the original.

Comment: @John: asking a question as an answer to a question is generally not a good idea, especially when an answer has already been accepted...

Comment: @John: LOL.  I linked to that exact question and said that it was answered (and has been accepted) with an earlier set of knowledge.  Now that the actual release has happened that question (or at least its accepted answer) is no longer relevant.

Comment: @Raphael: @Vaccano: I disagree. I see no reason for a second question. Instead, people should simply answer the original question, now that the answer is known.

Comment: @John, Happily you are the only one who thinks so (or at least voted so).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is no longer supported in Visual Studio (as of the 2010 version), and I doubt it'll ever be. ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t%28VS.100%29.aspx))

The new platform for Windows Phone 7 is Silverlight along with XNA for game development (read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535%28VS.92%29.aspx) for clarification, and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402528%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to decide which is the one you should use).

I think they ditched .NET CF (or at least in its previous form) in favor of the aforementioned frameworks.

If you read [this description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28VS.95%29.aspx), it is clear that Silverlight in Windows Phone is just a subset of Silverlight for desktop. There are also [articles about XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462085%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

The bottomline is:
It is still good old .NET, but it is no longer the old .NET CF.

Comment: -1: Please provide some proof of this, and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @John - I added some links for you.

Comment: Agreed.  "No longer" is innacurate, as VS120 never suuported device development in the first place, and what facts lead you to believe it never will?  Studio was ready to ship.  They certainly weren't going to hold that just for device support, but assuming it never will is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I see, you assert that Windows Phone will be the only device in the future. That all of the non-WinMo CE-based devices running CF apps now will cease to exist, or at least that no one will develop for them.

Comment: @ctacke - By "No longer", I mean "compared to the previos version".

Answer (score 2):

The [Microsoft statement linked in that older answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t%28VS.100%29.aspx) is still very valid.  Studio 10 does not include Smart Device development support.  It is supposed to come to us out-of-band, likely when the Windows Phone stuff stabilizes a bit more.