# .NET Compact Framework with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compact-framework

NET Compact Framework with Visual Studio 2010?
I have Visual Studio 2003, but i want change to one IDE.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625181/updates-to-net-compact-framework-in-2010

Answer (score 7):

Joel Fjordén has [a blog post](http://joel.fjorden.se/index.php?entry=entry091228-170025) on how to Open and Build .NET Compact Framework Projects in Visual Studio 2010.  In short, his approach involves editing the project file and copying the .NET Compact Framework v3.5 targets files to the .NET v4 directory.

As alluded to earlier, Microsoft web pages note the following:

> Because Visual Studio 2010 does not support mobile application development for Windows Phone prior to Windows Phone OS 7.0, you cannot use the following features: .NET Compact Framework projects, Visual C++ device projects, smart device CAB projects, Device Emulator and Device Emulator Manager, testing tools for device projects, and Device Security Manager.

- [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t%28VS.100%29.aspx)

> .NET Compact Framework application development is not supported in Visual Studio 2010.

- [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2.aspx)

> .NET Compact Framework application development is supported in Visual Studio 2008, but not in Visual Studio 2010.

- [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656764.aspx)

Unfortunately, none of these Microsoft pages appear to make any reference to an out-of-band release for Visual Studio 2010.  Is there a Microsoft blog or web page to monitor for an announcement on the availability of this out-of-band release?

Answer (score 5):

To be absolutely clear, Visual Studio 2010 did not ship with Smart Device Programmability support.  The primary reason for this is that the Windows Phone stuff was not fully ready, and Microsoft wasn't going hold the release of Studio waiting for that small piece.

Smart Device support for Visual Studio 2010 will be shipped out-of-band, probably in the coming months (they're already shipping CTPs of the bits, and since the Phone is due out later this year, they have to get tools into the hands of developers).

Now what will that "support" entail?  Microsoft hasn't officially announced the full details, but it's probably a good bet that you'll see:

- Compact Framework 3.5 (not 2.0 or 1.1) support for CE and WinMo 6.5
- Silverlight support for WinPhone
- XNA support for WinPhone

If you can't wait for that release, then your only real option is to use Studio 2005 or Studio 2008, but keep in mind that those will not work for WinPhone, and you'd be moving to al already out-of-date tool set.  I'd seriously consider waiting.

Now as a stopgap, you *might* be able to use the Evaluation version of Studio 2008 in hopes that the 2010 bits will be shipped before the time limit of the eval expires.  The challenge there is that since 2010 is now released, finding the 2008 eval might be difficult.

Comment: do you have any official MS response regarding the Compact Framework being available in the near future as part of VS 2010? It's July now, and it's still not there. For now I would assume, that MS is dropping CF support. Are there any official press releases on what's going on with this?

Comment: Microsoft has been very tight-lipped about the future of mobile development.  Windows Phone 7 support is already shipping as a CTP for Studio 2010, but for "other" platforms they've said nothing.  I sincerely doubt they are dropping CF support completely, though, since WinPhone uses it and the newly announced Windows Embedded Compact (CE) 7.0 has CF 3.5 included with it.  Implicitly that means you have at least 10 more years of support for it (since they support CE for that long).

Answer (score 3):

You can go [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010?wa=wsignin1.0) and vote to have Microsoft add Compact Framework Support for Visual Studio 2010.

I really makes sense for them to do this as there is no "replacement" Windows CE/Pocket PC yet (or probably ever).

**UPDATE:** MS has more or less abandoned existing feature requests in Connect.  Please go to the new [User Voice site to vote](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2145313-bring-back-support-for-smart-device-extensions) for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2.aspx

says ".NET Compact Framework application development is not supported in Visual Studio 2010".

I would recommend VS2008

Comment: This link show the .NET Framework 4.0.
I need use .NET Framework 1.0 (Compact Framework), i used with Visual Studio 2003. But i want use one.

Answer (score 0):

For a longer answer.
framework 1.* (compact or otherwise) is not really supported anymore. The lowest is 2.0.
I would ask what you are using the compact framework becuase Microsoft has different directions.

Their phone is going to silverlight and XNA.

If you are developing for smaller devices the .net micro kit is now free and open
http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/default.mspx

There are different directions depending on what exactly you are doing. This may be a time to evaluate what direction you want to take.